# How to call .net web service with jquery?

Tags: jquery, web-services

I want call a web service which is created in .net with soap client.

And now I want to call this web service with jQuery and display the result in my HTML5 page.

I am using following code, but getting the error only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://mysite.com/RSSReader.asmx/MY_method_name_in_web_service",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
            $('#RSSContent').removeClass('loading');

            // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
            $('#RSSContent').html(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Please suggest me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you take out `data: "{}",`?

Comment: It does not matter if I keep or remove data: "{}", line..
Because there is no change in result.
It does not enter in the success:...
And in error: it just displays the error keyword...

Comment: Error !! !! !!... But which error ?? ?? ??